# how to measure the page time load?

Tags: c#

I want to know how much time a specific code in my App takes ?!!!
Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class:

```
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// Run your code here
watch.Stop();
long milliseconds = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Comment: should I add something to use this class !!

Comment: @Rawhi, yes, you need to add the namespace this class has been declared into: `using  System.Diagnostics;`

Answer (score 0):

Aside from @Darins answer you won't be able to measure page load time on the client as they are across a network and there are many variables involved (i.e. You can start a javascript timer as the page would need loaded first). However anything on the server can be timed.

Comment: It should also be noted that trying to measure it from the client side would run into the problem of having to define what "is the page loaded?" means.  It's easy to determine when the DOM is finished loading, but from the user perspective there are any number of other resources which may still need to load.